# While-clause with a second conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions, will-would

I got myself all confused. Can a while-clause be used with a second conditional to talk about a hypothetical situation? If so, then which form of verb does the tense after "while" take?

I was taught that using "will" after will/when is incorrect, but I'm not sure if the past form of "will" works.For e.g:

> Person A : "Person 1 and Person 2 always seem to be engaged in an
>   argument. I wonder what would happen if they went to the movies with
>   person 3"
>
> 1) Person B: "If that happened, then they (person 1 and 2) would keep
>   arguing while person 3 **would be watching** it alone" (both actions would
>   occour at the same time)
>
> 2)Person B: "If that happened, then they would keep arguing while
>   person 3 **watches it alone**"
>
> 3) Person B: "If that happened, then they (person 1 and 2) would keep
>   arguing while person 3 **watched it alone**"
>
> 4) Person B: "If that
>   happened, then they (person 1 and 2) would keep arguing while person 3
>   **would watch it alone**"
>
> 5) Person B: "If that happened, then they (person 1 and 2) would keep
>   arguing while person 3 **is watching it alone**"

Another example to make things more clear.

Example 2:

> 1)If person 1 and person 2 were here at the party, then person 1 would
>   be drinking while person 2 **would be eating**.( both eating and drinking
>   would   happen at the same time)
>
> 2) If person 1 and person 2 were here at the party, then person 1
>   would be drinking while **person 2 is eating**.
>
> 3) If person 1 and person 2 were here at the party, then person 1
>   would be drinking while **person 2 ate**.
>
> 4) If person 1 and person 2 were here at the party, then person 1
>   would be drinking while **person 2 would eat**.
>
> 5) If person 1 and person 2 were here at the party, then person 1
>   would be drinking while **person 2 eats**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *I was taught that using "will" after will/when is incorrect* - were you taught this rule exactly?  Because it seems completely wrong to me.  One of the most famous nursery rhymes in English includes the line "**When** the bough breaks, the baby **will** fall."

Comment: My bad, I should've mentioned this earlier. I was told that I should avoid using "will" in the time-clause, and that's exactly what confuses me when I try to use "would" in a while-clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To talk about unreal situations now or in the future, we use a past tense in the if-clause and would+bare infinitive in the main clause.

> 1)If person 1 and person 2 were here at the party, then person 1 would be drinking while person 2 would be eating.( both eating and drinking would happen at the same time)

Let's change your sentence a bit.

> If they were here at the party, then he would be drinking and she would be eating.

*While* shows that both drinking and eating are simultaneous actions and we can use either continuous or simple tenses for both of them.

> If they were here at the party, then he would be drinking /would drink. while she would be eating/would eat.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. Your answer's perfect. My doubts have been eliminated.